# kimonolabs >Text before comma

Tags: regex

I'm trying to scrape a piece of text from a website using Kimonolabs. The text is succesfully scraped using the advanced setting:

```
div > div > ul > li.location > span.value
```

The text being scraped using this CSS selector is:

```
Cityname, streetname 1
```

However, I wish to delete everything before the comma so that only remains:

```
Cityname
```

I wish to do this with regex, but I'm totally ignorant about it. What I do konw is that it has to containof 3 blocks when using Kimonolabs: https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203043464-Manually-input-regular-expressions

Can anybody help me setting up the correct regex? All I got so far is the following, but it's not the correct markup for Kimonolabs (it doesn't allow for it in the dashboard):

```
^(.+?),
```

Comment: what's wrong with `string.split`?

Comment: Well, try - as it is shown in the pictures there - `/^()([^,]+)()/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs you referred to:

> The regular expression pattern in kimono is defined in three parts. **It's important that any custom regular expression you produce retains the *three part notation*, with the surrounding `( )` for each part**. The *first part* refers to the pattern to the left of the desired content. The *middle part* refers to the pattern that the desired content must match and the *third part* refers to the pattern to the right of the desired content.

So, you seem to need:

```
/^()([^,]+)()/
```

Or, `/(^)([^,]+)(,)/` (it should be equivalent), and the 2nd capture group (the *middle part*) should capture the `Cityname`.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Still, I think the second one should work judging by the regex syntax.